# Why $C=1$ in indefinite integral $\int{\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am reading Introduction to Calculus and Analysis by Richard Courant.
In Section 3.15, g.The Dirichlet Integral, it said $\int{\sin x \,\mathrm{d}x}=1-\cos x$,why $C=1$ here?

Comment: We have, for any constant $C$,
$
\int \sin x \:dx=-\cos x+C
$ since
$
(-\cos x+C)'=\sin x.
$ Then one is allowed to take $C=1$.

Comment: Because probably he wanted $\int_0^x\sin t\,dt=1-\cos x$

Comment: Is there any influence to the conclusion of $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin x}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} \,\mathrm{d}x}$ which is proofed convergent when takes $C<1$? @OlivierOloa

Comment: Ok, in this context, when making an integration by parts, we take $1-\cos x$ as an antiderivative of $\sin x$ in order to have a finite limit of $\frac{1-\cos x}{x}$ at $ x \to 0$ which wouldn't be the case with $\frac{-\cos x}{x}$. Do you see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, for any constant $C$,
$$
\int \sin x \:dx=-\cos x+C
$$ since
$$
(-\cos x+C)'=\sin x.
$$ Then one is allowed to take $C=1$.

In some cases, taking a *specific* value of the constant of integration is very useful. For example, when integrating by parts in the following evaluation,
$$
\int_{0}^M{\frac{\sin x}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x}=\left.\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\right|_0^M+\int_{0}^M{\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} \,\mathrm{d}x}
$$ the first term on the right hand side admits a *finite* limit as $x \to 0$ because of the choice of $1 -\cos x$ instead of the usual $-\cos x$ for the antiderivative of $\sin x$. Then one may easily conclude to the convergence of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^M{\frac{\sin x}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x}$ as $M \to \infty$.

Comment: I don't understand what's difference between using $1-\cos x$ or $-\cos x$,because they all in $[-1,1]$，and by L'Hopital's Rule:$\lim_{x->0}{\frac{-\cos x}{x}}=\frac{-\lim_{x->0}{(\cos x)'}}{\lim_{x->0}{x'}}$

Comment: @NFDream You can't apply L'Hospital rule here, this is *not* an undeterminate form, it is $\frac{\cos x}{x}$ $ \to$ '$ \frac10=\infty$'. It is *not* of the form $\frac{0}0$.

Comment: Oh,I understand now, thank you. @OlivierOloa

Comment: @NFDream You are welcome.